# Injecting no-interface ejb in a different ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb-3.1

I have a no-interface ejb deployed in an ear (MyEar.ear)

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyService{
// stuff
}
```

The ear is deployed to jboss-6.0.0.Final

I confirmed the JNDI name from the server jmx console:

MyEar/MyService/no-interface

I'm trying to reference this ejb from another ejb in a war (outside the ear) in the same server:

```
@EJB(mappedName = "MyEar/MyService/no-interface")
private MyService myService;
```

I'm referencing the ear project from the war project in eclipse, and compilation is successful.

I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException exception when deploying the war:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eg.com.test.MyService

Why is the ejb in the war not seeing the ejb from the other ear?

**Edit**: I updated to the follwing

*remote interface*

```
@Remote
public interface MyServiceRemote{
// stuff
}
```

*ejb*

```
@Stateless
public class MyService implements MyServiceRemote{
// stuff
}
```

*ejb reference in a different application*

```
@EJB(mappedName = "MyEar/MyService/remote")
private MyServiceRemote myService;
```

I verified the new JNDI name on the server: MyEar/MyService/remote

But i'm still getting the same exception, this time the interface not found:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eg.com.test.MyServiceRemote

**Update**: I needed to package the Remote Interface with the war, its working correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That EJB would need to have a remote interface, and you would access it the same as any remote EJB from the external WAR. The external WAR has a seperate class loader to the EAR, hence it will not find EAR classes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm still getting an exception. I updated the question to reflect your answer.

Comment: Set your mapped name in the @Stateless annotation as well.

Comment: unfortunately this had no effect, the exception is still there. This makes sense as i already verified the current name exists form the server JNDI console.

Comment: I found the Issue, i needed to package the remote Interface in the WAR.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a fully qualified name for referencing EJB in another application using EJB 3.1 portable naming format:

```
java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-bean-interface-name>
```

Comment: can you please specify more with the question's example